Looker Studio, 7-Days Rolling Average

Based on the Date and the Spend Column, I am trying to calculate the 7-Days average of the Meta Spend, I am not entirely sure how this is achieved in looker studio, as i need a formula that sums the Amount spent over the last 7 days and then divides it by 7
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(TODAY(), Date) <= 7 AND DATE_DIFF(TODAY(), Date) >= 0 THEN Amount spent ELSE 0 END) / 7


Divides each row by 7, but does not calculate the rolling average for the column giving me



Could you please convert the (large) images of your data to actual tables?

Ihar Vakulski has a great blog post explaining how to do this
https://www.vakulski-group.com/blog/post/rolling-and-moving-average-in-google-data-studio-looker-studio/
